# certificate error in browser but not InfoPath

Tags: infopath, certificate, digital-signature

We have created a form in Infopath 2010 for use with SharePoint 2010.  The form contains digital signatures.  If I open the form in InfoPath the DS loads with no problem.  However, if I open the form from the browser, IE9, I get a "Revocation Status cannot be verified" error.  How can I troubleshoot/fix/supress the error?

Thanks

Comment: Has this problem been resolved? I'm having similar issues. Thanks, Chuck

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add the cert's root certs into central admin.  You do this under security and manage trust.

Comment: +1 This could be the reason. Make sure you have added root certificates to your CA. Here is the link on how to do it: http://falakmahmood.blogspot.se/2011/07/how-to-add-root-certificate-as-trusting.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually one gets such error when the Infopath itself is used for generating a certificate instead of getting it from a Certificate Authority but it was not exported from development machine where it was generated and imported into computer store on Sharepoint server as Trusted Root CA.
You might find it useful this description in msdn forum [How to create certificate for infopath forms](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sv/sharepoint2010customization/thread/5c3b12f6-ab72-4129-9141-6f0c0ee269fe)

Note also that:

- List Templates, in contrast to Form Library Templates, do not support that digital signing - cf. Table 3 of [Building SharePoint Applications with InfoPath 2010 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961896.aspx)
- If a form template was designed based on an XML Schema, you can enable digital signatures for that form template only if the XML Schema has a node that is in the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) XML digital signature namespace. 
  Read [Digital Signatures in InfoPath 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/digital-signatures-in-infopath-2010-HA010381868.aspx)
- The Signature Line control is only available in InfoPath 2010 client (Filler) form but unsupported in Web browser form. 
  Read [Digital Signatures in InfoPath 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/digital-signatures-in-infopath-2010-HA010381868.aspx)